# How to use @GeneratedValue in a non pk field

Tags: java, jpa, sequence

I would like to know how we could use a sequence in JPA. We have a non-pk field which value must come from a sequence in DB. How could I update that value updating the entity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277630/hibernate-jpa-sequence-non-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA defines `@GeneratedValue` to apply to just PK fields. DataNucleus accepts it on *any* field. Obviously that is beyond the JPA spec and other implementations may not support such behaviour.