# JPA: Is there a way to return the next availble PK

Tags: java, jpa

if the field `id` inside my `Entity` is like this

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

then when I `persist` the Entity, a unique random Id is created. Is there a way that I can retrieve the next available PK before `persist`

Comment: which jpa implementation are you using?

Comment: Maybe this similar question can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067986/calling-next-value-of-a-sequence-in-jpa

Answer (score 2):

There isn't in the spec, although some implementations may provide a means.  The problem is the ID is generated by the database in some cases, whether by a sequence or a autoincrement.  It's too challenging for JPA to know exactly what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what you are planning to do with the id when you have it, I found this [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CustomSequencing) that may be helpful. I would write a custom sequence class that just calls the super methods to generate the id but then do what you need to do once you have it.

Comment: This might be a stupid reason. I was just brainstorm on how I would tackle the problem. I am trying to create user profile. The user allow to upload their picture before click `Create User`. So I want to use the same `userId` for the image name, but I wont know that `userId`, until I `persist` the user.

Answer (score 1):

In EclipseLink you can do this buy,

```
Number nextId = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).getNextSequenceNumberValue(MyEntity.class);
```

Comment: What is the `Session.class`? Is it an import?

Comment: After look around, is `Session` -> `org.hibernate.Session`. I am using EclipseLink, dont think I have that.

Answer (score 0):

@Harry Pham
See the Eclipselink User Guide:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Ids/GeneratedValue

At the bottom it states what James already said. You can use the following code to obtain the next sequence number value:

```
long id = em.unwrap(Session.class).getNextSequenceNumberValue(Employee.class).longValue();
```

The Session class is in package org.eclipselink.persistence.Sessions.

But using this is eclipselink proprietary and not JPA.

Comment: I just did a quick test for an entity with generation strategy "IDENTITY". It did not work for me. `getNextSequenceNumberValue()` returned 0, which was not correct. Maybe it works only under certain circumstances, which are not obvious.

Comment: You cannot preallocate an IDENTITY id, it requires an insert.  In general I would never recommend IDENTITY, use TABLE or SEQUENCE.