# Any idea why H2 parser throws an exception at Oracle SQL statement "Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT SUBJECT_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM[*] DUAL"?

Tags: sql, hibernate

I've the following error when injecting EntityManager:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert (SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert (StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT SUBJECT_SEQ.NEXTVAL  FROM[*] DUAL "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement: select SUBJECT_SEQ.nextval from dual [42001-173]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:171)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:196)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readColumnIdentifier(Parser.java:2846)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTermObjectDot(Parser.java:2401)
```

Snippet of persistence.cfg:

```
    <class>gov.dhs.obim.domain.bm.Vendor</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:bm/password@localhost:1521:XE"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="obim"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@Stateless


@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://docs.oasis-
open.org/org.oasis.bias/ns/org.oasis.bias-1.0/", name = "BIAS_v1")
public class BIASV1Impl implements BIASV1 {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "OBIM_BIAS2")
    EntityManager em;



@Override
public EnrollResponsePackage enroll(EnrollRequest enrollRequest)
        throws BIASFaultMessage {


    Subject subject = new Subject();
    Encounter encounter = new Encounter();
    subject.addEncounter(encounter);

    assert(subject.getEncounters().contains(encounter));
    assert(encounter.getSubject() == subject);


    em.persist(subject);
    em.persist(encounter);

    return null;
}
```

Any idea why injection of EntityManager caused the parser to revalidate SQL statement
`SELECT SUBJECT_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM[*] DUAL`?

This caused resulting error

```
 org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert
(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert
(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386888/get-next-sequence-value-from-database-using-hibernate.

Comment: This solution does not apply to my issue. In my case, I let JPA handles the sequence generation, which is specified in the pojo module.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea why my injection of EntityManager failed?