# Grails 3 - globally incremented number

Tags: spring, grails, grails-orm

I have a global number that gets incremented frequently but gets reset yearly. Right now I'm storing this global number as a single row:

```
class GlobalCounter {
    Integer counter = 0
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

When I increment it, I use a lock in a transaction:

```
    def globalCounter = GlobalCounter.lock(1)
    globalCounter.counter = globalCounter.counter + 1
    globalCounter.save()
    globalCounter.discard()
```

The problem is that when I update it frequently, I get an exception instead of the code waiting:

```
Transaction (Process ID 61) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

I know that when you add a new row, the database gives the option of using a primary key with auto increment, so I think this should be possible without deadlocks. How can I do it?

Comment: What's the underlying database? If it's Oracle you could use a sequence, https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php, other database vendors have similar offerings

Comment: We're using SQL Server and unfortunately do not have the option of switching to Oracle.

Comment: I did say other database vendors have similar offerings, https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/sequences.php

Comment: I'll take a look.

Comment: I got it working using a combination of your comment and https://stackoverflow.com/a/38761760/443044. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to post an answer, I can accept it. I did get it working.