# JPA : how to generate a common id?

Tags: jpa

I need to allocate a same unique id (batchid) for each row inserted in a BD during a batch execution as illustrated below.

```
| id | batchid |
| -- | ------- |
| 1  | 1       |
| 2  | 1       |
| 3  | 2       |
| 4  | 2       |
| 5  | 2       |
| 6  | 3       |
```

Was wondering if there is an automated way to do it with jpa annotation, like with a sequence ?

Comment: You may query your database and get the next value from a sequence table, q.v. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386888/get-next-sequence-value-from-database-using-hibernate).  One of the answers is even database agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Did it for now this way:

```java
@Repository
public interface SeqRepository extends JpaRepository<CsvEntity, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT nextval('batch_id_seq')", nativeQuery = true)
    Integer getNextBatchId();
}
```

schema.sql

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS batch_id_seq
INCREMENT 1
START 1;
```