# Postgresql Spring Data @GeneratedValue without @Id return null value

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

im working in spring boot project i want to map a property with serial (using my sequence) column in my table and this column is not the ID.
i found this solution :

```
  @Column(name = "DEMANDE_NUMBER", insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
  private Integer demandeNumber;
```

(because @GeneratedValue persist null and doesn't use the sequence)

this solution works fine and the field is persisted in my DB and the value uses the sequence but when i get my object after saving using my repository the demandeNumber is null

```
    Demande savedDemande= demandeRepository.save(demandeToSave);
   //demandeObj .getDemandeNumber() return null
```

any suggestion to resolve this issue please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate JPA Sequence (non-Id)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277630/hibernate-jpa-sequence-non-id)

Comment: @UladzislauKaminski i already used this answer where i found the suggestion insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "serial"   but the problem persist since i can't get the presisted column after save :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to this answer [How to use a sequence generator for a non ID field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495399/how-to-use-a-sequence-generator-for-a-non-id-field)

i added the following annotation on my property

```
  @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
  @Column(name = "column_name", columnDefinition = "serial", updatable = false)
```

you should import the package from hibernate and not javax.persistence.

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Generated;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenerationTime;
```

i hope this can help other people in the future. note this solution is for spring data with postgresql.