# How to generate a sequence with hibernate and spring (non-primary key)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need to generate and ID for non-primary key for oracle, and I'm stuck about it. I tested
**GeneratedValue**, **SequenceGenerator** and **Genereted** as I read that GeneratedValue works only for @Id property, I've seen a bunch of articles and questions about this (like this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277630/hibernate-jpa-sequence-non-id)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277630/hibernate-jpa-sequence-non-id) but nothing worked for me except the generating and ID using UUID but that's not how I want it.
Let's cosider I have this entity

```
@Entity 
@Table
public class ClassA {

    @Id
    private Long id;

   private Long seq_val;

   // Getters & Setters

}
```

What I need is that every time the data gets saved to databse a new key gets generate in **seq_val**
Please anyone has an example

Comment: Check the top answer for this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495399/how-to-use-a-sequence-generator-for-a-non-id-field.