# JPA: Usage of @GeneratedValue on non-id column

Tags: jpa

I am attempting to persist an entity with an attribute that I want to be populated from a DB sequence. I'm using Oracle, have created the sequence, verified the sequence works via sql, and yet my attribute isn't getting populated. Here's what I have:

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "RFQ_LINE_IDS_SEQUENCE", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name="RFQ_LINE_IDS_SEQUENCE", sequenceName="RFQ_LINE_IDS_SEQUENCE", allocationSize=1000000000)
@Column(name = "external_line_item_id")
private String externalLineItemId;
```

All the examples I'm seen online show this annotation being used with @Id, but I have another attribute that I'm using for my id.

I've also tried the following to no avail:

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "RFQ_LINE_IDS_SEQUENCE", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@GenericGenerator(name = "RFQ_LINE_IDS_SEQUENCE", strategy = "sequence",
  parameters = {@Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "RFQ_LINE_IDS_SEQUENCE")})
@Column(name = "external_line_item_id")
private String externalLineItemId;
```

Comment: ugh... I just realized this may be a dup:
[hibernate-jpa-sequence-non-id][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277630/hibernate-jpa-sequence-non-id

Answer (score 4):

JPA only mandates support for @GeneratedValue on @Id fields. Some JPA implementations (such as [DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2)) support it but not all do.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a proposal for JPA to support `@GeneratedValue` for non-id attributes. Please vote here for this to be included in 2.2
https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-113