# Generator for non-id column

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I'm trying to get a generator to work for both the id column and use another sequence for a different, non-id column.

This doesn't seem to do anything. The column is still null after doing a save (in integration tests).

```
   static mapping = {
      id generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'id_seq']
      otherCol generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'other_seq']
      version true
   }
```

Comment: Not the nicest, but what's stopping you populating the value beforeInsert?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the generator option only works for id columns. It is based on Hibernate @GeneratedValue which is always used in conjunction with the @Id annotation.

See:

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/single.html#identity

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator

[Hibernate JPA Sequence (non-Id)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277630/hibernate-jpa-sequence-non-id/536102#536102)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use the [sequence-generator plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/sequence-generator) for grails. As i understand it, it emulates the behavior of a database sequence because of the restriction of the grails / hibernate generators.

I had a pretty similar problem and this plugin solved it. It has some additional features like that you can define a prefix for a sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I stumbled across this when looking around for a solution to my original question. Does it support using database sequences, however?

Comment: From the [docs](https://github.com/goeh/grails-sequence-generator#annotation-sequenceentity), it says that the plugin does not use database sequences, because of the lack of flexibility that the plugin want's to achieve. Nevertheless you can at least db unique settings.