# @GeneratedValue doesn't work at non id field

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, entity

I would like to make a unique field "number" with autogeneration(autoincrement, last number + 1). But it is not an id field. How can i reach that? @GeneratedValue doesn't work. Only id was generated. My code doens't work.

**My entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "public")
public class Policeman implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long number;

    @Column
    private String fam;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String otch;

   //setters getters
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This SO question looked the same: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277630/hibernate-jpa-sequence-non-id)

It says that the @GeneratedValue annotation is only used in conjunction with @Id to create auto-numbers. It cannot be used with non-id columns. However, there is a workaround that suggests to create a separate entity with a generated Id, something like this:

```
@Entity
public class GeneralSequenceNumber {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long number;
}

@Entity
@Table(schema = "public")
public class Policeman implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(...)
    private GeneralSequnceNumber myVal;

    @Column
    private String fam;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String otch;

   //setters getters
}
```

You can also refer to the following link for more details on this work-around:[Link2](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2405140)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i think it is too redundantly use additional class to solve this simple problem