# generate auto-incremented field in java spring data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, liquibase

I need to create a auto-incremented key (not a primary key) to use it as a file-name in spring-data
here what i tried:

```java
@NotNull
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "BODY_FILE")
private long bodyFile;
```

in liquibase:

```
- column:
     name: BODY_FILE
     type: BIGINT
     autoIncrement: true
```

but the field bodyfile is always 0.

Comment: `@GeneratedValue` is only for `@Id` fields, it will not work on regular columns.

Comment: is there no other way to do this for regular columns ?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/536102/4437074

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Generated value will **ONLY work with a primary key.**

It won't work with fields that are not a primary key.

It won't even work with the composite primary key.

**But why not generated type can be applied for the non-primary field?**

A possible answer is most of the older version of DB either does not support the AUTO_INCREMENT (Generated value) for the non-primary key field or If they support in a newer version that too has constraints- like for MySQL 
There can be only one AUTO_INCREMENT column per table, it must be indexed, and it cannot have a DEFAULT value.

**So from where this zero comes from in your DB?**

It is because of your datatype 'Long' its default value is getting stored in your DB.

For more details on @Generated value [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html)